# Generating a 'natural path' along a spline

Tags: math, 3d, matrix, spline

I need a way to get an orientation (local x/y/z axes) at any point along a spline... where the z-axis is always the spline tangent and x/y are perpendicular to each other and z.

One common technique is to calculate one axis vector as the rate of change of the tangent, i.e. `x(t) = z(t) X z(t+dt)`
Then y is simply `x X z`.

However I am not sure this gives what I'd call the 'natural' orientation path. What I mean by that is, imagine I have a rigid steel rod which is bend into some set of curls and I then advance a flexible hose along this rod. If friction is neglible, the 'natural' path would mean the hose ends up with minimum torque at any point, as it would 'untwist' itself to get a lower-energy state.

Is there any way to do this which doesn't mean traversing the spline's length from 0-t to find the transform at a given point t?

Comment: Consider moving your qw to http://math.stackexchange.com. (Good qw but probably not programming related. I am out of "moderator flags for today").

Comment: I have done basic spline in MATLAB. Perhaps they have some documentation (perhaps not. sometimes documentation there is "skimmy").

Comment: @OlofEdler - thing is this is both math and programming. But since many topics in games/graphics programming _depend_ on math, I think it's OK here.

Comment: I see many questions here that is _related_ to programming (Definitions of things. Social aspects of programming). F.e. I would assume one could be a programmer forever, not knowing what a spline is. I'd say that your qw is math entirely, therefor perhaps better answered elsewhere. Buuut, I am not too strict. Feel free to have your qw. Our opinions of what is proper here simply differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for [Frenet frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) - moving trihedron with unit tangent, normal and binormal vectors

Addition.
simple example:

X = 2*t^2-t+5

Y = t^3+t^2+2*t - 1

Z = -t^3 - 2*Sin(t)

---

X'(t) = 4*t-1; X'' = 4

Y'=3*t^2 + 2*t + 2; Y'' = 6*t+2

Z'= -3*t^2-2*Cos(t); Z'' = -6*t+2*Sin(t)

---

At parameter t = 0:

X' = -1; Y' = 2; Z' = -2; |R'| = Sqrt(1 + 4 + 4) = 3

T = (-1/3, 2/3, - 2/3)

and so on...

Comment: That's a bit mathy for me... it looks very similar to @tom10's answer but more formalized?

Comment: How is your spline defined? I hope, it is possible to calculate curve derivatives (1st and 2nd). Then you may apply formulas from part "Other expressions of the frame"

Comment: It is simply a set of 3D points used as input to a 3rd-party Catmull-Rom; I've been treating that as a black box but I suppose internally it should use mathematical representations.

Comment: Yes, every Catmull-Rom spline piece has analytic representation (q(t) here: http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/catmull/ )

Comment: I tried this but by T and B vectors aren't orthogonal - see on Math site: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103924/generating-orthogonal-axes-on-a-spline. I think Tom's answer actually covered more practical steps but is gone now, any way to find it?

Comment: T and B vectors MUST be orthogonal, because B is the cross product of T and N.

Comment: Turns out there is an extra cross-product I needed. I'm marking this as answered but actually Frenet doesn't achieve the _natural path_ part... I started a thread on Math site for that: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103976/generate-a-natural-path-through-a-set-of-3d-points